Change escape characters of substitutions in dired-do-shell-command
I've recently found nushell and made it my default shell, and in many ways it's great, but the syntax does differ a bit from bash, and that causes substitutions to be wrong when I use dired-do-shell-command to spawn a terminal. For instance, I had a command
          ("\\.mp3" "xterm -e \"mplayer * \" &")

I used to play mp3s in their own terminal so I could use Emacs in the meantime, but now I get an error message:
   1  │ xterm -e "mplayer -af scaletempo Parallax\ Vlog\ May\ 2024.mp3 " & wait
        ·                                           ───────────┬──────────
        ·                                                      ╰── unrecognized escape after '\' in string

For those who can't see on their screens, nushell writes "unrecognized escape after '\' in string" underneath the latter part of the command.
I think what it wants is something like mplayer -af scaletempo `Parallax Vlog May 2024.mp3` , with the backticks indicating to nushell that their interior should be read as one name. If I run that in vterm, it works. So I need to change the escape characters used in the export by dired-do-shell-command. Is there any non-hacky way I can do that? I looked around in the dired file but got lost pretty quick.

What is the error? Who produces that error? All I can see is escaped spaces which are necessary in order to tell the shell that starts mplayer that Parallax Vlog May 2024.mp3 is a single file name. Can you please clarify? How do you know that it's these escaped spaces that are the problem? What syntax does nush want instead of \ ?

@NickD This might be cut off on your screen but nushell writes "unrecognized escape after '' in string" underneath the latter part of the command. I think what it wants is something like mplayer -af scaletempo Parallax Vlog May 2024.mp3 . If I run that in vterm, it works.

Please add your last comment to the question.

The escaping is done by shell-quote-argument (see the code here) and doing C-h f shell-quote-argument says among other things: This function is designed to work with the syntax of your system’s standard shell, and might produce incorrect results with unusual shells. See Info node ‘(elisp)Security Considerations’.  So it's not going to be simple. I recommend your post an RFE for the Emacs developers to consider (M-x report-emacs-bug).

Can youy fix your edit? There seems to be some junk after the .mp3 that should probably be deleted,

@NickD Ah, I see. I was trying to surround Parallax Vlog… with backticks, which is how nushell can tell it's a name, that's where the junk came from. How can I do this without it being parsed as code by Stackexchange?

This (that nu requires backticks in order to quote spaces in a file name) should be added to your question. See the edit that I made for a possible solution to how can I include a backtick inside backticks.
